# REST PUT method seems to work but doesn't edit an entity

Tags: rest, jakarta-ee, jpa

I have a REST Web Service API. I mapped database using JPA. I have an entity "persona". Adding a new entity with POST method works fine, also GET method works fine, but when I try to call PUT method, there is some exception that I found out while debugging: "Cannot suppress a null exception." and "Self-suppression not permitted". In the test database with other entities everything works fine...
Adding works almost the same like editing in my case - firstly I only get the values and then after changing I do everything the same, the only difference is that there is used method PUT instead of POST.

This is my PUT method (here the exception occurs):

```
 @PUT
@Consumes({"application/xml", "application/json"})
public Response edit(Persona entity) {
    try {
        getJpaController().edit(entity);
        return Response.ok().build();
    } catch (Exception ex) {
        return Response.notModified(ex.getMessage()).build();
    }
}
```

I'm working first time with web services, so I'm a newbie.

What can be the reason of such behaviour? What is this self-suppression error?

If you need any source code else, please, tell me, I will edit my post.

@EDIT:

I found some exception in JpaController Class, my Persona class has:

```
@OneToOne(cascade = CascadeType.ALL, mappedBy = "persona")
    private Personaacceso personaacceso;
```

In JpaController there is:

```
Personaacceso personaaccesoOld = persistentPersona.getPersonaacceso();
            Personaacceso personaaccesoNew = persona.getPersonaacceso();

if (personaaccesoOld != null && !personaaccesoOld.equals(personaaccesoNew)) {
                if (illegalOrphanMessages == null) {
                    illegalOrphanMessages = new ArrayList<String>();
                }
                illegalOrphanMessages.add("You must retain Personaacceso " + personaaccesoOld + " since its persona field is not nullable.");
            }
```

So there is showing a message that I have to retain Personaacceso. Any idea how to solve it?

Comment: where did your transaction start ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Okey, I know what was the reason now...

Each Persona entity has some other entities (one-to-one or one-to-many). The Jpa Controller wasn't retaining all these containing entities (instead, it was creating new ones). So, the data was lost and because of that persona entity wasn't edited.

Solution:
To every containing entity do something like:

```
containedEntityNew=containedEntityOld;
```

However, take into consideration, that then these entity-fields are just rewrited from the old "main" entity.